# Kendo toolbar update overflow text

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, toolbar

my kendo toolbar has items using template and overflowtemplate, e.g.

**template:**

```
<label id='piName'>Hello</label>
```

**overflowtemplate:**

```
<label id='piName'>Hello</label>
```

In runtime, based on conditions, I want to update the words in the overflow popup (say from Hello to Good) Anyone know who to do it in js/jquery?  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is not kendo specific, just DOM manipulation. You have already given the element an id, so just select for that and update the content:

```
$("#piName").text("Good");
```

As an aside, elements ids should be unique for html to be semantically correct so I would recommend using a different one in each template. Or perhaps you can use a class which does not need to be unique and additionally gives you the option to style the label with css:

```
<label class='toolbar-label'>Hello</label>
$(".toolbar-label").text("Good");
```